# Can this be considered a formal proof?

Tags: solution-verification

I am still learning about mathematical proofs and wanted to ask for some feedback, if possible, of my solution for the following problem.

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $x-y$ is even if and only if $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity.

To prove this I used a Lemma and the following theorem:

**Theorem 16** Let $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity if and only if $x+y$ is even.

My approach was the following:

**Lemma**  If $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $n$ and $-n$ are of the same parity.
To prove this lemma we consider two cases.
*Case 1.* Assume $n$ is even. Then $n=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $-n=-(2k)=2(-k)$.
Since $-k$ is an integer, it follows that $n$ is even.
Case 2. Let $n$ be odd. Then $n=2k+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $-n=-(2k+1)=-2k-1=-2k-2+1=2(-k-1)+1$. Since $-k-1$ is an integer, $-n$ is odd.

We now proceed to prove the result.
Let $x$ and $y$ be of opposite parity. By lemma, $x+(-y)$ is a sum of two integers of opposite parity. Therefore, by theorem 16, $x-y$ is odd.
For the converse, assume $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity. By lemma, $x+(-y)$ is a sum of two integers of the same parity. Therefore, by theorem 16, $x-y$ is even.

Thank you for your attention :).

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It looks like you started from the axioms and then proceeded your way to a proof which one of many ways to do a proof. From what I am told, this is called a synthetic proof. Check out this article. It really helps: https://deopurkar.github.io/teaching/algebra1/cheng.pdf

Comment: The question "Can this be considered a formal proof?" has an answer. That answer is "no". A formal proof is basically a proof so precise and which so rigidly follows formal rules that a machine could check the proof to verify it's correct. That doesn't take anything away from your proof, which is perfectly fine and rigorous.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and links for information!! Sorry for using the term "formal proof" in an incorrect way (I had no idea it was a specific term lol). I think what I meant was "rigorous proof" (and this was clarified by the feedback from everyone). Despite of that, I surely learned something new which is always welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an elaboration on my comment:

The question "Can this be considered a formal proof?" has an answer. That answer is "no". A formal proof is basically a proof so precise and which so rigidly follows formal rules that a machine could check the proof to verify it's correct. That doesn't take anything away from your proof, which is perfectly fine and rigorous.

A formal proof must take place in a specified formal system. Some examples of formal systems are [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction), and Hilbert-style [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system).

There are also variants of [dependent type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+type+theory) which can be used as formal systems, though these are not commonly taught or used in undergraduate mathematics.

Your proof is "informal" in the sense that although it is a correct proof, it is not a formal proof in any of the above styles. It can, however, be translated into a formal proof in an obvious way. It is therefore rigorous.